# RStudio/MySQL connection error: Plugin sha256_password could not be loaded

Tags: mysql, r, connection

I am new to both MySQL and RStudio. I am getting the following error in RSTudio:
**Failed to connect to database: Error: Plugin sha256_password could not be loaded: The specified module could not be found.**

I would greatly appreciate some guidance.

1)
I am trying to add a connection with the following code:

```
con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "world")
```

2) I did some research earlier.

> a) I made the following change in my.ini in
>   c:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0. Still getting error.
>
> b) Restarted MySQL server in services.

```
default_authentication_plugin=caching_sha2_password  <-- commented existing line
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password    <--- added new line
```

Comment: you have alspo tpo change the user to native pasword

Comment: @nbk - Thank You. I am very new to MySQL, trying to find out how to change the user to native password. Looks like I need to use MySQL shell, trying to find out the next steps. In the meantime if some details can be provided that would be helpful.